# how to get rid of Unsupported module in scripts: http for jsreport

Tags: jsreport

```
Error occured - Error during rendering report: Unsupported module in scripts: http. To enable require on particular module, you need to update the configuration as {"scripts": { "allowedModules": ["http"] } } ... Alternatively you can also set "*" to allowedModules to enable everything
```

Stak - Error: Unsupported module in scripts: http. To enable require on particular module, you need to update the configuration as {"scripts": { "allowedModules": ["http"] } } ... Alternatively you can also set "*" to allowedModules to enable everything
    at _require (/Users/ravikirankk/Projects/I-Team/srdm/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-scripts/lib/scriptEvalChild.js:44:11)
    at evalmachine.:2:12
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:32:29)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:38:15)
    at Object.runInNewContext (vm.js:91:38)
    at module.exports (/Users/ravikirankk/Projects/I-Team/srdm/jsreport/node_modules/jsreport-scripts/lib/scriptEvalChild.js:123:6)
    at process. (/Users/ravikirankk/Projects/I-Team/srdm/jsreport/node_modules/script-manager/lib/worker-processes.js:48:36)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:766:12)

Answer (score 1):

```
require('jsreport')({ "scripts": {
"allowedModules" : ["http"]
```

}
})

Update the require statement in server.js file